# load datagrid ItemsSource from a Page to a Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am developing an application which uses `NavigationWindow` as follows:

1. `NavigationWindow` as `Mainwindow`.
2. `Page0.xaml` which has a 2 `DataGrid's` (dgMaster and dgDetail) in `Master Detail` scenairo.
3. `Window1.xaml` which will be displayed as `ShowDialog()` on dgDetails's `Row_DoubleClick's` event setter as follows:

`Code behind`

```
public void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 my_Window = new Window1();
    my_Window.ShowDialog();
}
```

For point number 2, the code snippet is as follows:

```
// on datagrid row selection changed, it should load the ItemsSource in the Window1 datagrid. dg3 is the datagrid in Window1. 
private void dgDetails_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.db = new testDB_Entities();
    string IDMapper = (dgDetails.SelectedItem as Details).Name;
    var Query1 = from a in this.db.Details
               orderby a.ID == IDMapper
               select a;

    dg3.DataContext = null;
    dg3.DataContext = Query1;
    dg3.Items.Refresh();
}
```

The above codes together displays the `Window` as a `DialogBox`, but the `DataGrid` is empty. How to load the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` in `Window1.xaml` from the `Page0.xaml dgDetails_SelectionChanged` event?

I understand that these controls belong separately to each xaml files, but is there a way to display a controls datacontext from another xaml ( regardless a page /window).

if anybody dont understand the question. please let me know.. i will try to explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, the question is to load the gridview in the window. 
In that case, one option is creating a public collection (list) in the window and set the item source of the dg3 with this public list.

```
public List<String> source {set;get}
```

in the constructor

```
Window()
{
    \\initialize
    dg3.ItemSources=source;
}
```

when you the dgdetail selection changed, assign the list in the window the collection from the dgdetail.

```
private void dgDetails_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
   this.db = new testDB_Entities();
   string IDMapper = (dgDetails.SelectedItem as Details).Name;
   var Query1 = (from a in this.db.Details
               orderby a.ID == IDMapper
               select a).ToList();
```

my_Window.source=Query1;

```
   }
```

Comment: if it makes sense vote, otherwise let me here some details about the problem.

Comment: thanks for the update, but pls can you tel me where should I play the List<String> .. in my page or window ?

Comment: On double click event in the datagrid located on Page0, a dialog box is shown( which is window1 which has been already designed with datagrid). I have to load this datagrid on the dialog box.

Comment: It is just a property for the Window from. possibly like public class Window1 :window{ public List<String> source {get;set} public Window1(){InitilizeComponent(); dg.ItemSource=source; }}

Answer (score 1):

You are using selection changed event and yet you are opening the window.xaml using ShowDialog(),

ShowDialog() will lock out the page and thus cannot change selection,

If you are using ShowDialog() and just wish to display in a dialog why not just pass the Paramater (I think it is:

```
string IDMapper = (dgDetails.SelectedItem as Details).Name
```

To the Constructor of the Window?

```
public void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

 string IDMapper = (dgDetails.SelectedItem as Details).Name;
 Window1 my_Window = new Window1(IDMapper );
 my_Window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then perform your query in the Window constructor or Loaded event

```
Window(string IDMapper)
{
    var Query1 = (from a in this.db.Details
               orderby a.ID == IDMapper
               select a).ToList();
}
```

You would need access to the data from both Page and Window, you should move your EF into a datalayer which both have access to the Context, failing that you just pass the Query result list to the Window constructor

You should also choose a different name for your Window.xaml to avoid confusion as you are conflicting with Window and thus having Window1,